# Hibernate Envers is not working for hibernate-spring-maven project

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am trying to use Envers to audit the updates/inserts into my tables.

I am using Hibernate 4.1.8.Final and spring 3.0.2.RELEASE and for envers 
my pom.xml looks like this.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
    </dependency
```

I have configued my spring-servlet.xml

```
`<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                  <!-- <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update" >org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener </prop>

            </props>

        </property>
```

`and my hibernat-cfg.xml look like this`

```
 <property name="org.hibernate.envers.auditTableSuffix">_AUD</property>
 <property name="org.hibernate.envers.revisionFieldName">ID_REVISION_INFO</property>
 <property name="org.hibernate.envers.revisionTypeFieldName">REVISION_TYPE</property>



 <mapping class="com.example.contact.form.Contact" />`
```

and in my dto i am using @audited annotation to use envers,
There is no exception,normal insert and update are fine  . I googled so  many times ,tried many possible solution ,still its not working. Can any one help me to come out from this ??

Comment: With Envers4 you don't need the event listeners, they will get added automatically. Also you should probably have all the properties inone place (spring-servlet.xml). Can you try breakpointing at EnversIntegrator.integrate and AuditConfiguration.getFor, to see if they are called?

Comment: thanks @adamw , now its working fine , there was version miss-match of hibernate and envers